# pulling variables from .txt

Tags: javascript, html

Please tell me this is possible. I have a .txt file with data arranged like a spreadsheet (i would use excel instead but i dont have it and am broke) and would like to pull from it and assign as a variable.
Ex. (bla.txt) 
first line is headers
Second is data
A|B|C
1|2|3
Would like to have them assigned as

```
Var x= A1
Var y= B2
Var z= C3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Ps. All is on a closed circuit so no security issues.

Comment: It would be a whole lot easier to use this data in JavaScript if it's in JSON format.  Either way, what you'd do is make an AJAX request to the server to get the file contents, then parse the data from the response.

Comment: what have you attempted so far?

Comment: Parsing that is pretty easy with `split()`. Mapping it to an object might be a little harder though, since JavaScript doesn't have a built-in `zip()` function or a (I think) a dict-from-pairs function.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could post your .txt file.

*Also if you would like to use excel but cant afford it you should try [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) or [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/). They are both free and (at least LibreOffice is) FOSS.*

To load this file into your javascript you can use Jquery to load it like this:

```
$.get('/path/to/data.txt', function(data) {    //Gets file 'data.txt' and stores it in variable 'data'
    //Code to execute after loading file
    /*I’m not sure exactly how your .txt file is formatted so I don't know
      How you want it stored into separate variables.
      But you can do that here*/
});
```

Hopefully this at least helps you get started.

Answer (score 0):

This simple code might help for extracting the data from individual lines.

**Note**: But this will work when you have one character only between `|`

example

> A|B|C 1|2|3

but will not work for

> AA|BC|CS 11|2|3

Here it is

```
var line = "A|B|C 1|2|3";
var x = line.charAt(0) + line.charAt(6);
var y = line.charAt(2) + line.charAt(8);
var z = line.charAt(4) + line.charAt(10);
```

Use other string functions to get your job done for the second case i pointed out.

Refer to this w3schools page for more help http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp